# How to keep columns content visible (sticky) in a 3 columns layout?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a three columns layout. The main column have much contents than the two others.

- When the user is scrolling down he is seeing a lots of blank spaces due to the empty columns.
- On facebook when the user is scrolling, once the right column has no more content, it  sticks to the bottom of the page
- so there are always content in this column.

I have no idea how to achieve this, so any idea, jquery plugin or how to will be appreciated.

I'm using the following technologies in my current project:
* jquery
* twitter bootstrap 3

This is important to note the column content can be higher than the page itself, so bootstrap affix will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used margin-top to move the columns. Take a look at https://github.com/collective/collective.rcse/blob/93f47d15694c7f71635d1117342d2b84ea85bab7/collective/rcse/resources/dev/js/theme-desktop.js#L797 to see the function.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [Sticky-Kit Plugin](http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/). It works absolutely fine in different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

This stuff can be done using the jQuery and CSS. 
Check this out-  http://jsfiddle.net/MAPNk/

Here is a small work.

These are few steps I followed:

1. Called a function on scroll
2. Check height of sidebar and of window.  // window is monitor size.
3. if (height of sidebar < height of window), change the `position of sidebar` to `fixed`
   and `top` to `0 (or where the div start)`.
4. else if ( bottom of window > bottom of sidebar), change the `position of sidebar` to `fixed` and `bottom` to `0`.

The above conditions are preformed when scrolling down.  Similarly remove position or make it absolute on scrolling up.

Try out the rest and you will definitely find out. :)